# What is "Py" in Ray casting terminology?

Tags: python, casting, pygame, raycasting

I am followin this [tutorial](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/raycast/rayc7.html) for doing a ray casting tutorial with python and pygame. But the problem is that in the algorithm for checking intersections in the grid he uses an abreviature never explained before("Py") I first thought that was the number pi but it isn't.

Can anynone who has done this tutorial or know the raycasting concept explain me what it is? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Py is the y coordinate of the point P. This is shown in the diagram at the top of the page where it says `P (Px, Py)`.

Comment: Thanks! I am blind xD. I will accept your answer when stackoverflow lets me.